# How to express optional matching using Query String Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a query as below using the [query string dsl](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)  which I'm expecting to return results that match all the three assertions. (status = active, price = 100 , language = en).

How can I make the `language` param optional, just score lower if is not matching instead to not match at all ?

```
(status:"active") AND (price:100) AND (language:"en")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
(status:active AND language:en) OR (price:100 AND language:en)
```

Or a shorter version like this:

```
+status:active +price:100 language:en
```

An equivalent query rewritten using `bool` and `match` queries is this one:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "match": {
          "status": "active"
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "price": 100
        }
      }
    ],
    "should": {
      "match": {
        "language": "en"
      }
    }
  }
}
```